# Vscode open current file in new split window on right shortcut key

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I was using visual studio code and wanted to open the current open file in duplicate split window on the right.
Is there a shortcut key for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>

This will duplicate the window and open the current file in a window on the right, and you can access the windows using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> to switch between left and right.

Comment: that's a tab, not a window.   a window would have it's own decorations, side bar, etc, and be completely separate.  (downvote)